# Correct project/build setup for DI

Tags: c#, deployment, dependency-injection

Hopefully a straightforward one.  I'm looking at a C# product, destined to perhaps have desktop (WPF), web, any number of mobile build outputs thanks to Xamarin.

There are several components:

- I have a "CoreApi" project which has interfaces and shared models which can be called upon to write any app front end (and implemented to write a back end).
- I also have all 'app logic' in another assembly - currently in a similar style to View Models from the MVVM pattern, but with an app focus.
- There's a platform-specific implementation of an interface contained in applogic, which relates to dynamically generating audio buffers for playback.  Separate project/assembly too

I'm using Ninject, and it works well.  But as the solution grows to include other project types (web, mobile clients) I can foresee some 'smells':

Currently the client project has references to the platform-specific (DirectX) audio engine and the local/test implementation of the backend.  It still uses Ninject and doesn't refer to the implementation classes directly, but having them accessible and directly referenced like that feels wrong.

I almost want to have different 'packages' when the solution builds:

- Package 1: the desktop client + DirectX engine + backend X
- Package 2: Web Deploy package with backend Y
- Package 3: Android version with backend X + Android audio engine...

Am I on the right track?  Do I really want to resort to a post-build step, xcopying things to a target folder?

Comment: Will this be handled when you package it anyway? What will Xamarin's packaging do, for example?

Comment: I've no idea - I wouldn't want to depend on that, since I'm not just creating Xamarin packages

Comment: Really, this question is about the larger problem: I'm using DI, but how should I put together the different implementation modules without using Add Reference, in a neat/clean way?

Comment: I suspect this is something you could use MEF for. I'm not sure I'd exactly _advocate_ that, but it's worth a quick look.

Comment: MEF is a DI framework, but I pointed out I'm already using Ninject :)

Comment: My apologies, I'm used to DI on a smaller scale, for unit testing. I don't have an authoritative answer for you. If you are using a CI/build/deployment server (you should be!), you should probably set up separate builds for the different packages, which may obviate the need for post-build steps. If you find you need to test locally, post-build steps may be the easiest way (again depending on your CI/build server)

Comment: I'd love to help out but I'm not getting the picture from the explanation. Could you add a diagram to the question visualizing the different assemblies (specifying what they hold), external references and how they are dependant on each other?

Comment: Could you let me know which part you don't understand and I will try to clarify?

Comment: suggestion-- can you post a diagram of the process?

Comment: I'd expect a solution for the server, and one for each client, probably sharing a couple library projects, like the CoreAPI, between solutions.

Comment: @flup - what does that have to do with packing? projects dictate build output, not solutions.  Can you explain.. at all?

Comment: You can add a [deployment project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to each solution.

Comment: I don't want a deployment project, and that *still* doesn't have anything to do with creating separate solutions. What exactly are you getting at?

Comment: Might be a stupid one, but why can't you just create different solutions?

Comment: And I might be missing something but if you're are using DI then you can deploy your components independently, so why can't you have a build process that builds each of those components (web, desktop..) packs them and then deploys them all together?

Comment: Solutions can't configure build output, they're just collections of projects.  I can't see how a specific solution would pull together components in a particular way - the projects would just build to their output folders, wouldn't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at using MSBuild features to perform the necessary copies. I've taken the approach of using dependency.proj files which you can configure to perform the appropriate copy actions depending on any configuration options you choose to setup e.g. you can copy specific files into the output folders based on configuration and CPU type. I wouldn't advocate using the old style post build steps as these are unreliable and hard to debug. MSBuild is the way forward in my opinion.